# What is the difference of asyntask parameter in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Well as my question says, i refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It tells me

```
  Asyntask <params, progress, result>
```

but i did not use progress. and is it state according to your arrangement? or it has a rule?

FOr example:

```
   class loadingdata extends AsyncTask<?,?,?>
   protected void onPreExecute() {}
   protected String doInBackground(String... args) {} 
   protected void onPostExecute() {}
```

so should I insert the 3 parameter as

```
asyntask <void String void> ?
```

or it has a rule of

```
<preExecute, postExecute, doInBackground> or so fourth?
```

please help me with this, I am a beginner to this and i dont understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need one or more of the `AsyncTask` parameters then use `Void` (note the capital V so it is `Void` and not `void`).

In the signature of `AsyncTask<params, progress, result>`, the first is the type of an array passed to `doInBackground()`, the second is the type of an array used when calling `publishProgress()` which calls `onProgressUpdate()` and the third is the data type returned by `doInBackdround()` and passed to `onPostExecute()`.

For example...

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
```

...would mean the method signatures would be...

```
doInBackground(String... params)
onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
onPostExecute(Boolean result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since AsyncTask has generic parameters, you *must* provide all of them. If you don't use any of them, then the type you provide doesn't really matter.

Comment: but how should I know doInBackground should be place in which situation.. or I can just simply put at any situation and any other 2 will be void? It will take it automatically?

Comment: @user2198192 What are you trying to accomplish with AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

The Types are Generic so u can use any of the class or primitive type. When you want execute The statement in AsyncTasks use it by making a instance of it and then call execute() for that instance.

goto: http://mysecretishelloworld.blogspot.in/2013/04/asynctask-usage-guide.html

for more detail use of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask's generic types

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
3. **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. **To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:**

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask { ... }

Example

```
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
 }

 URL parameter for doInBackground(URL... urls)
 You call publishProgress((int)somevalue) in doinBackground() to update progress.
 Integer parameter for onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)  
 Long (result) parameter for onPostExecute(). The result is received from doInBackground().
```

Usage

```
  new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```